# Cannot assign "str" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a post request to django rest api from reactjs but the traceback shows,
`ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x00000247410D3670>": "BuildingClearance.resident_number" must be a "User" instance.`

**models.py**

```
class BuildingClearance(models.Model):
    
    resident_number = models.ForeignKey(to=User, to_field="resident_number", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    maintenance_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class BuildingClearanceList(ListCreateAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = BuildingClearanceSerializer
    queryset = BuildingClearance.objects.all()

    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(resident_number=self.request.user)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(resident_number=self.request.user)

class BuildingClearanceView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = BuildingClearanceSerializer
    queryset = BuildingClearance.objects.all()

    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
            return serializer.save(resident_number=self.request.user)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(resident_number=self.request.user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BuildingClearanceSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=BuildingClearance
        exclude = ['resident_number']
```

If i set the **permission_classes** to **[isAuthenticated]**, the error message will be 401 unauthorized (Authentication credentials were not provided) even though i included the right headers:

**services.js**

```
const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/";

buildingClearance(maintenance_type) {
        var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).access;
        console.log(token)
        return axios
        .post(API_URL + "building/", {
            headers:{
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            maintenance_type

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replac this code

```
class BuildingClearance(models.Model):
    
    resident_number = models.ForeignKey(to=User, to_field="resident_number", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
   
   resident_number = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="resident_number", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

To read more infomation about models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/

Comment: Hi sir, I tried to do your suggestion, but it still gives me a 401 error.